# When importing a JSON .js file with only a default object, assigning to state works but using in React doesn't

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Edited:

We have a JSON file env.prod.js that looks like this:

```
export default {
  debug: false,
  // 3rd Party APIs
  Google: { /* all the rest of the object */
}
```

The import in our container page is:

```
import env from "../../env"
```

~~(Our build takes care of adding the .prod when building for production)~~

We have ../../env/index.js that does this:

```
import devenv from './env.dev';
import prodenv from './env.prod';

let env;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') env = devenv;
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') env = prodenv;

export default env;
```

So I changed the import to:

```
import env from "../../env/index"
```

with no differences... and also:

```
import { env } from "../../env/index"
```

with no differences.

When assigning to state, env works fine:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    foo = null;
    this.foo = new FooService(env.Fooconfig); /* this fails */
    this.state = {
    ...
    tunesTracks: env.tunesTracks, /* this works */
    ...
    }
    
}
```

If I hover over env, I can see that it has:

Module

> default {debug: false, Fooconfig: ...}

Fooconfig is not directly under env, but under env.default.Fooconfig

If I use:

```
this.foo = new FooService(env.default.Fooconfig);
```

I still get errors:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2560 TypeError: Cannot read property 
'Fooconfig' of undefined
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Fooconfig' 
of undefined
```

Why isn't the env object including all the items in the default() object directly? Why do I get Typerrors if I use the env.default.Fooconfig

Many thanks!

Comment: This can't have anything to do with React specifically, if anything it has something to do with the build system you are using (e.g. webpack). But you are not providing enough information to be able to figure out what's going on here. You are saying that the build tool takes care of adding the right file suffix... is there anything else it might do to `env`?

Comment: @FelixKling I updated the question because I missed the need to import index.js from the env/ folder.

Comment: If it says that FooConfig is a property of the default object and you ```import env from './../..etc'``` then you should call it as env.FooConfig. Hovering over the module and seeing default just means that it is the default object not the name of the object. When you have that import line, you import the default object but give it the alias ```env```